# Como detectar se uma tecla especifica foi pressionada em Batch?

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Eu quero fazer um .Bat que veja se uma tecla especifica foi pressionada, e se foi fazer uma coisa. Ex:

```
If tecla D foi pressionada goto teste
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o comando `choice`, em conjunto com o parâmetro `/c` para determinar as opções possíveis, em conjunto, o retorno desse comando `%errorlevel%` é apresentado a posição numérica de `choice`. Podendo assim, ser verificado a sua equivalência (`EQU`)

**Exemplo com uma tecla apenas:**

```
choice /c d
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto teste
:teste
echo 'Clicou d'
```

**Exemplo com multiplas teclas:**

```
choice /c asd
if "%errorlevel%" EQU 1 (goto 1)
if "%errorlevel%" EQU 2 (goto 2)
if "%errorlevel%" EQU 3 (goto 3)

:1
echo. 'Clicou a' &pause >nul
:2
echo. 'Clicou s' &pause >nul
:3
echo. 'Clicou d' &pause >nul
```

Comment: Cara eu botei o GED e não foi tentei botar EQU e também não foi, meu código esta igual ao seu, mas quando eu aperto a, s ou d ele fecha

Comment: Você lembrou de adicionar os pontos para que ele pularia? ```:1```, ```:2``` e ```:3```?

Comment: Sim, eu botei isso. Mas já achei um outro código, obrigado por me mostrar o comando choice, pois com ele consegui fazer oque eu queria.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Realizada correção conceitual, erro ocorrido devido a utilização de outro Shell.

Answer (score 1):

- Usando input do usuário:

  **1.** Leia o input do usuário

  **2.** Salve em uma variável

  **3.** Compare as opções válidas/pré-definidas com a variável

  **4.** Direcione para o tratamento/label correspondente a tecla

  **5.** Implemente um tratamento para opções erradas no input

```
@echo off

rem :: ----------------------------------------------------------
rem :: seu código para ações antes do teste de tecla pressinada
rem :: ----------------------------------------------------------

set /p "_Tecla=Use input para verificar qual tecla foi presionada: "

if /i "%_Tecla%" == "A" (
     goto :Label_Tecla_A
    )else if /i "%_Tecla%" == "B" (
     goto :Label_Tecla_B
    )else if /i "%_Tecla%" == "C" (
     goto :Label_Tecla_C
    )else if /i "%_Tecla%" == "D" (
     goto :Label_Tecla_D
    )else goto :Label_Tecla_Errada

:Label_Tecla_A
echo\Tecla Pressionada: A
echo\Executando tarefas do :Label_Tecla_A
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para Tecla pressinada A
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_Tecla_B
echo\Tecla Pressionada: B
echo\Executando tarefas do :Label_Tecla_B
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para Tecla pressinada B
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_Tecla_C
echo\Tecla Pressionada: C
echo\Executando tarefas do :Label_Tecla_C
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para Tecla pressinada C
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_Tecla_D
echo\Tecla Pressionada: D
echo\Executando tarefas do :Label_Tecla_D
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para Tecla pressinada D
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_Tecla_Errada
echo\Tecla Pressionada difere de: [A, B, C ^& D] 
echo\Executando tarefas do :Label_Tecla_Errada: %_Tecla%
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para Tecla pressinada D
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof
```

---

- Usando comando `choice` com uma opção definida como `padrão` e `timeout`:

  **1.** Estabeleça um tempo limite e uma ação padrão

  **2.** Crie `:label` usando o `ErrorLevel` (simplifique)

```
@echo off

rem :: -----------------------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo açoes antes do teste de Tecla pressinada
rem :: -----------------------------------------------------

choice /c ABCD /N /D C /T 5 /M "[ Teste tecla pressionada... ]"

goto :Label_%ErrorLevel%

:Label_1
rem :: ErrorLevel 1  e usado como default/padrão: /D C 
rem :: funciona só em conjunto com timeout + segundos: /T 5
echo\Tecla Pressionada: A
echo\Executando tarefas do :label_1 tecla A
rem :: ...
goto :eof

:Label_2
rem :: ErrorLevel 2
echo\Tecla Pressionada: B
echo\Executando tarefas do :label_2 tecla B
rem :: ...
goto :eof

:Label_3
rem :: ErrorLevel 3
echo\Tecla Pressionada: C
echo\Executando tarefas do :label_3 tecla C
rem :: ...
goto :eof

:Label_4
rem :: ErrorLevel 4
echo\Tecla Pressionada: D
echo\Executando tarefas do :label_4 tecla 4
rem :: ...
goto :eof
```

---

Usando comando choice com uma opção definida como padrão, com timeout e `if (condição) else if (coutras condições)`:

1. Estabeleça um tempo limite e uma ação padrão
2. Crie :label usando o ErrorLevel (simplifique), ou letra correspondente (documente)
3. Verifique entre as opções válidas, qual foi escolhida

```
@echo off

rem :: -----------------------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo açoes antes do teste de tecla pressinada
rem :: -----------------------------------------------------

choice /c ABCD /N /D C /T 5 /M "[ Teste tecla pressionada... ]"

if %ErrorLevel% equ 1 (
     goto :Label_1
    )else if %ErrorLevel% equ 2 (
     goto :Label_2
    )else if %ErrorLevel% equ 3 (
     goto :Label_3
    )else if %ErrorLevel% equ 4 (
     goto :Label_4
    )
    
goto :eof

:Label_1
rem :: ErrorLevel 1  e usado como default/padrão: /D C 
rem :: funciona só em conjunto com timeout + segundos: /T 5
echo\ Tecla Pressionada: A
echo\ executando tarefas do :label_1 tecla A
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para tecla pressinada A
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_2
rem :: ErrorLevel 2
echo\ Tecla Pressionada: B
echo\ executando tarefas do :label_2 tecla B
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para tecla pressinada B
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_3
rem :: ErrorLevel 3
echo\ Tecla Pressionada: C
echo\ executando tarefas do :label_3 tecla C
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para tecla pressinada C
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof

:Label_4
rem :: ErrorLevel 4
echo\ Tecla Pressionada: D
echo\ executando tarefas do :label_4 tecla 4
rem :: --------------------------------------
rem :: seu codigo para tecla pressinada D
rem :: --------------------------------------
goto :eof
```

---

Considere consultar documentação, no seu `prompt` digite:

**[`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
**[`Label /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
**[`Choice /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

Comment: Gostei da resposta apresentada, bem mais intuitivo.